# Change constant variable in constants.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, constants

I have constants.py file that has like few constants. And I want to be able to change them so on the next run of the app they would have the new values.

Beside reading the content from the file, do some replacements and re-save it, is there any normal way with python to do it? Any library or so?

Can't find anything on the internet so far.

Thanks

Comment: Probably just use a JSON file. The builtin json library can parse and serialize json, and you'll get to manipulate the constants with a python dictionary interface

Comment: This isn't very constant. :)

Comment: Some constants are constantly changing

Comment: it looks like `config` not `constants` - and you could use files like JSON, `.ini`, `.yaml` to keep it. Probably in Python 3.11 you could use `.toml` (it was added as default module). See [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)